# OpenGL: in shader program, how much more does a+sign*b (sign is a parameter and here is -1) cost than a-b?

Tags: opengl, fragment-shader

In shader program, 
I have a parameter:

```
uniform int sign
```

In main code, there is oen command:

```
a+sign*b
```

When the input parameter

```
sign = -1
```

a+sign*b is equal to

```
a-b
```

My question is:
How much more does a+sign*b (sign is a parameter and here is -1) cost than a-b?

a+sign*b needs one add, one multiply.

a-b only needs one subtract

Does this mean it is better to have two shader programs to handle the two situations of sign (1 and -1)?

[Update 1]
How about another situation, like in the shader program, we have:

```
uniform float x1;
uniform float x2;

void main(void) {
    float a = x1 * x2 * b;
}
```

Do we need to calculate x1*x2 outside of the shader program, or we could put here and the compiler will optimize the shader code? Similar to the first case of sign I mentioned earlier.

Comment: Here's an extra option: `a + (b ^ sign) - sign`

Comment: @harold: Only works if a and b are integers and two complement.

Comment: Depends on the hardware. Most graphiccards have a [fused multiply-add operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply%E2%80%93accumulate_operation), thus a+sign*b might result in only one operation.

Comment: Yes, and `sign` would have to be 0 or -1, not 1 or 1

Comment: @BDL, that is I am thinking. I am not sure whether some shader code has been optimized by considering the values of the input parameters.

Comment: @harold: This will definitly result in more operations. In the ops question, it is on modern graphiccards most likely that this line will only result in a single MAD instruction.

Comment: @BLD, OK, so you mean modern graphiccards can handle simple situations and optimize the code. Do we have some links to refer to?

Comment: @BDL sure, on modern ones. Not too long ago there wasn't even an instruction for a 32bit multiply.

Comment: @user1914692: [General Optimization Rules](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLSL_Optimizations); [GLSL fma reference](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/fma.xhtml), if you want to use the function form

Comment: @BDL, "General Optimization Rules" is a very good reference.

Answer (score 2):

Before you get to the point of trying to squeeze single cycles out of your shader code, you should be confident about a few things:

- That you have taken advantage of other types of optimizations (on CPU and GPU), where there might be much lower hanging fruit.
- That you are GPU limited.
- That the shader you are optimizing is among the ones that consumes the most time.
- That the shader is limited by processing power, and not for example by texture fetching.

Once micro-optimization is really the best thing to do, you have two main options:

- Benchmark. Which might be quite challenging for cases like this, because you need very stable and repeatable measurements to evaluate such small differences.
- Use performance analysis tools.

Most of the larger GPU vendors provide performance analysis tools. For this level of optimization, you should probably look into them if you haven't done that yet. Here is a typical example (PVRShaderEditor from Imagination), which lets you see shader assembly code, and gives you cycle/performance estimates:

http://blog.imgtec.com/powervr/the-latest-powervr-sdk-v3-4-and-tools-are-live
http://community.imgtec.com/developers/powervr/tools/pvrshadereditor

Other vendors will most likely have similar tools. You can normally find them by browsing the Developer areas on their web sites.

Answer (score 1):

This question is impossible to answer, because it depends on the way a particular OpenGL handles it. For example a particular implementation may detect by runtime analysis, that `sign` is either -1 or +1 and will create two optimized variants of the shader program for these two cases.

Comment: did you mean sometimes the runtime analysis can optmize, sometimes it might not?

Comment: In your coding practice, do you write two shader programs for the two situations? I have a lot of similar situations. I am thinking how to handle such kind of situations.

Comment: @user1914692: Yes, runtime analysis is rather diffuse and can do only so much. And yes, if I am confronted with needing two very similar shaders, but distinct in details like yours I normally create two distinct shader objects. In recent enough OpenGL you can have separable shader objects which reduce the complexity. But normally I'm using an in-house library (sorry, not public), that generates GLSL code from an abstract representation in which such multiple codepaths can be represented.